# Upload system-generated file to S3 using ActiveStorage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I have a need to upload a system-generated file to S3. I'm aware that I could use something like the AWS Ruby SDK for this. However, I'm already using ActiveStorage elsewhere in my application and it seems simpler, if possible, to use ActiveStorage for everything rather than ActiveStorage plus some other library.

Is this possible using ActiveStorage?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the answer in [this part of the documentation](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#attaching-file-io-objects):

```
@message.image.attach(io: File.open('/path/to/file'), filename: 'file.pdf')
```